# Clipping by mask results in blank output

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, clip

After clipping by mask in QGIS 3.6 the output file has been blank (empty). Raster file and vector mask file have the same projected CRS:

```
USER:100029 - * Generated CRS (+proj=igh +a=6370997 +b=6370997 +units=m +no_defs)
```

How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try checking for errors in the vector mask file using **Geometry checker** and **Topology checker** plugin. I had the same problem once and fixing the errors in the vector file did the trick.